# Framer motion page transition simplify code

Tags: reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

So the idea is to give fade in and out to components when route changes

**`App.js`**:

```
<AnimatePresence>
 <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
   <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
   <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
   <Route exact path='/people' component={People} />
   <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin} />
 </Switch>
</AnimatePresence>
```

**`All the pages`**:

```
const container = {
 hidden: {opacity: 0}
 visible: {opacity: 1}
}
<motion.div variants={container} 
            initial='hidden' 
            animate='visible' 
            exit='hidden'>
 ...
</motion.div>
```

How can i do it so that i write it once and apply to all?